# Which SQL mode to add to allow data truncation of char types with warning?

Tags: mysql

I'm running a MySQL 5.7 server (hosted on AWS RDS) and I want to disable insert/update rejection due to supplied strings exceeding the defined data type length. Currently, my java app gets a MysqlDataTruncation exception in these cases and I would prefer auto truncation to happen. The current value for `sql_mode` is `0` on the server configuration, but I'm confused about which of the following allowed values I need to add:

```
0
ANSI
ALLOW_INVALID_DATES
ANSI_QUOTES
ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO
HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE
IGNORE_SPACE
NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER
NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO
NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES
NO_DIR_IN_CREATE
NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
NO_FIELD_OPTIONS
NO_KEY_OPTIONS
NO_TABLE_OPTIONS
NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION
NO_ZERO_DATE
NO_ZERO_IN_DATE
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY
PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH
PIPES_AS_CONCAT
REAL_AS_FLOAT
STRICT_ALL_TABLES
STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
TRADITIONAL
```

My understanding is that STRICT_ALL_TABLES will effectively enable strict mode, which is what causes the errors/rejection instead of truncation/warning, but that mode is not set, so why would it still be happening?

Running `SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;` and `SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;` from a client both return an empty response.

Comment: Perhaps ignore extensions to INSERT and UPDATE eg insert..ignore, Update..ignore

Comment: But won't that result in the row not being inserted/updated? What I want is for the update to happen with the relevant values truncated if necessary.

Comment: 'But won't that result in the row not being inserted/updated?' - not necessarily you should review the documentation to see if it's suitable for you.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html https://dbfiddle.uk/8Ye8wruY